# ADS resetting row number on change of id variable returns false

Tags: sql, window-functions, row-number, advantage-database-server

I'm using version Advantage Database Server: 10.10.0.49.

I am trying to create a row number which resets on change of id.

I've tested similar code on MySQL and it works.

With Advantage the variables both return 'false' rather than the expected values.

I've created this test code in the ADS Architect.

```
drop table test;

create table test (id varchar(5),descrip varchar(10));

insert into test (id,descrip) values ('1','abc');
insert into test (id,descrip) values ('1','xyz');
insert into test (id,descrip) values ('1','hij');
insert into test (id,descrip) values ('2','abc');
insert into test (id,descrip) values ('2','hij');

set @ids = '';
set @row_num = 0;

select 
 @row_num = case when @ids = id then @row_num + 1 else 1 end AS row_num
,@ids = id as ids
,id
,descrip
from
test
order by
id
```

...which returns

```
Item | row_num | ids  |id |descrip
-----|---------|------|---|--------
1    |FALSE    |FALSE |1  |abc
2    |FALSE    |FALSE |1  |xyz
3    |FALSE    |FALSE |1  |hij
4    |FALSE    |FALSE |2  |abc
5    |FALSE    |FALSE |2  |hij
```

...and I was expecting

```
Item | row_num | ids  |id |descrip
-----|---------|------|---|--------
1    |1        |1     |1  |abc
2    |2        |1     |1  |xyz
3    |3        |1     |1  |hij
4    |1        |2     |2  |abc
5    |2        |2     |2  |hij
```

`Over` .. `Partition By` isn't supported by ADS as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning values to variables inside a SELECT statement does not work in ADS.

You get a BOOL result, because the `=` sign is interpreted as the comparison operator instead.

As far as I know you have to implement the window function yourself using a cursor (which might not be the best solution on the performance side, but it works):

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @rn INTEGER;
DECLARE @c CURSOR AS SELECT item, id FROM #test2 ORDER BY id, descrip;

TRY DROP TABLE #test; CATCH ALL END TRY;

CREATE TABLE #test (item INTEGER, id VARCHAR(5), descrip VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #test (item, id, descrip) VALUES (1, '1', 'abc');
INSERT INTO #test (item, id, descrip) VALUES (2, '1', 'xyz');
INSERT INTO #test (item, id, descrip) VALUES (3, '1', 'hij');
INSERT INTO #test (item, id, descrip) VALUES (4, '2', 'abc');
INSERT INTO #test (item, id, descrip) VALUES (5, '2', 'hij');

TRY DROP TABLE #test2; CATCH ALL END TRY;

SELECT
    tab.*
  , 0     AS "rn"
INTO #test2 
FROM #test tab;

@id = '';
OPEN @c;
WHILE FETCH @c DO
  IF @id <> @c.id THEN
    @id = @c.id;
    @rn = 1;
  ELSE
    @rn = @rn + 1;
  END IF;

  UPDATE #test2 SET rn = @rn WHERE item = @c.item;

END WHILE ;
CLOSE @c;

SELECT * FROM #test2 ORDER BY id, rn;
```

Note: I have ordered the items by `id, descrip`, instead of just `id` as in your question. You should choose an adequate ordering for your situation.

Comment: Thanks Jens, that works. I just need to map it to my real data now - that could be tricky as it's an unfamiliar method to me but you've been a great help.